# Software to play MP3s slowed down with pitch correction

Tags: linux, software-rec, audio, mp3

I'm looking for software that will help me transcribe music from MP3 files. I'd like to be able to select a portion of the song, and then have the software play it back to me at a selectable slower speed while correcting the pitch.

Answer (score 3):

Basically there are 2 kinds of ways to do pitch-correcting tempo changes: 'interactively' (you can turn the 'tempo knob' while playing the song) or in 'batch mode' (apply the tempo change as an effect, then play the song again).

Interactive:

- [Transcribe!](http://www.seventhstring.com/xscribe/overview.html) can do it but it is non-free (cheap though)
- [SlowMP3](http://www.rinki.net/pekka/slowmp3) can do it and is free of charge (but not open-source) and doesn't seem to work together with your general ALSA configuration very well (I guess because it's Java-based)
- [stretchplayer](http://www.teuton.org/~gabriel/stretchplayer) is nice but it does not support mp3 for [patent liability reasons](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/FAQ.html#Q020)

Batch mode:

- [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net)
- the [rubberband commandline tool](http://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/)
- mplayer (`mplayer -af scaletempo -speed .7`)

Comment: i never understood the "free-as-in-beer" term; beer isn't free. Windows 7 is free-as-in-beer: it costs money.

Comment: Basically the point is the word 'free' has 2 meanings: freedom (as used in the expression 'free speech') and free of charge (as used in the expression 'free beer'). "free-as-in-beer" is shorthand for "free as used in the expression 'free beer'", i.e. free of charge but not 'liberated'. I'll update the answer to use less confusing terminology. More on the subject at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre

Comment: Yeah, i've read that wikipedia page; and directed co-workers to read it too. We still didn't get it. i wasn't saying that the answer needed to be updated - i was just throwing a random comment out there on a random answer i happen to have read.

Comment: @IanBoyd "free-as-in-beer" is short for "free-as-in-free-beer" i.e. beer you do not pay money for or which is gratis. It is used in contrast with "free-as-in-free-speech" i.e. a freedom that may (or may not) be gratis - for software this means software that adheres to the Free Software Definition (http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). Microsoft Windows 7 is neither free-as-in-free-beer nor free-as-in-free-speech.

Answer (score 2):

A few are mentioned [here](http://www.mombu.com/gnu_linux/ubuntu/t-mp3-player-with-pitch-functionality-8925229.html). I used amarok plugin some years ago if I remember correctly.